# Prove an algebra $F$ is & $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Prove the algebra $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if is closed by disjoint numerable unions.

My answer is:

1. $F$ is closed by disjoint numerable unions so the algebra $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, I used the negation in both ways, so if $F$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra and it is an algebra the property of closed numerable-infinite union is the one that $F$  don't obey so $\cup_{i \in I} A_i$ $\notin \sigma$-algebra, so the disjoint numerable unions aren't closed.
2. And from the other way my doubt is when do I have to use that the union is disjoint to prove that no disjoint numerable unions so $F$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $F$ is already an algebra, we must check that it also closed under the countable union of events in $F$.

So, let $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of events in $F$. We show that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \in F$.

Define $B_1 := A_1$ and for $n \geq 2$, define recursively $B_n:= A_n\setminus B_{n-1}$. Then clearly

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$$

and since the sequence $(B_n)_n$ is pairwise disjoint, the hypothesis allows us to conclude. $\quad \square$